# how to assign XML values to string in Vb6

Tags: vb6

I want to assign below mentioned xml values to a string like this

```
Dim test As String

test = ... ?
```

Where the XML should contain:

```
      <RptVer>1</RptVer>

      <RptTyp>1</RptTyp>

    </RptInfo>

</InstRptRoot>
```

How can I do this and also preserve the formatting (ie linebreaks, spacing, etc.)?

Comment: `test = "<RptInfo><RptVer>1</RptVer><RptTyp>1</RptTyp></RptInfo>"`  ?

Comment: how to add spaces if it goes beyond one line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Mark answered your question, I'll answer your second question:

```
Dim test As String

test = "<RptInfo>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       vbTab & "<RptVer>1</RptVer>" & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
       vbTab & "<RptTyp>1</RptTyp> & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & _
      "</RptInfo>"
```

Assuming you want it double-spaced and indented.  You had also missed the leading tag, but MarkL caught that as well.

Comment: It can also be worth mentioning that xml processing wise, the CrLf and Tabs are not necessary.  They only make it more human readable.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I was looking for